# Global Variables in jquery nested functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, scope

Are global variables accessible in jquery nested functions?
Im having an issue that i cant solve. One object property changes and another one doesn't

The situtation is this

```
    for(var key in object) {
        if(object[key].boolean) {
            alert(object[key].value)
            $.get(url, "data", function(data) {
                if(parseInt(data) > object[key].int) {
                    alert(object[key].value);
                    object.int = data;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The issue i am having is the object[key].value does not hold its value. Both alerts have different values so i cant use it in the nested return function. Also object[key].int gets updated correctly which is more confusing. Object is declared as a global variable.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show a complete example that demonstrates the issue, preferably a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I think you would need to do `var obj = object[key];` where your first alert is (before the ajax call) to make it work.

Comment: Create a new local scope. Use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) instead of `for(..){..}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your anonymous wrapper is called only after get becomes success,it is not called right away, looks like some situation like

[Return a function from the anonymous wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200279/return-a-function-from-the-anonymous-wrapper)

are you getting the last item alerted from the inside closure?

```
var object = {
    x:10,
    y:20,
    z:30
};
for(var key in object) {
            console.log("outside closure",object[key]);
                $.get("/echo/html?data=asdf" ,(function(keyAlias) {
                    return function(data) {
                        console.log("inside closure",object[keyAlias],data);
                        //your logis goes here
                    }
                 })(key));
    }
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eTdv5/1/ (check console logs)

Explaining the whole thing is not becessary as I guess, you can check the above mentioned SO post, In case of anything unclear please ask.

**Explanation:**

First, `key = 10`

```
$.get("/echo/html?data=asdf" , <at this place key is 10> );
```

`(function(key) {})(key)` is like calling `display(key)`, think that you are writing display function right away and calling it with an argument `key`.

`return function(data) {};` will return a function, in effect think like `(function(key) {})(key)` getting replaced with this returned function.

That will give you an introduction, now how the scope is managed:

The `key` will change its value as the `for in` loop loops through `object`, but each callback function we created has its own `keyAlias` assosiated with it which corresponds to the value of `key` at the time callback function was crated using `(function(key) {})(key)`

Comment: Yeah the item is getting alerted, except the value is different from the original alert

Comment: Are you always getting last key in object alerted from inner function.

Comment: I figured it out, since the ajax request handles asynchronously, the object was still getting loop through by the for loop, so by the time the request came back, the object reference was a different one.

Comment: @CBaker exactly, you should create individual persistend scopes for storing data in each run of loop,

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more, I'm pretty new to jquery and javascript

Comment: another interesting way is to use synchronous ajax requests. which eventually is the solution i decided to use

Comment: @CBaker Yes but that is not a recommended approach as it can hang the browser till request is finished. The 'A' in AJAX is 'Asynchronous' right? Better dont break the base design :) Obviously decisions depend on problem at hand, time etc.

Comment: so for your previous example, you pass the key into the nested function, when i try to specific two paramters, ie. the data returned and the key, it errors saying object[key] is undefined. Can you specific two paramters?

Comment: @CBaker Make it 'return function(data){...}'

Comment: thats works very well, thank you very much for the help. Do you mind kind of going through and explaining how this all works? I cant quite grasp it