# Jquery each() goes faster as load()

Tags: jquery, load, each

I have something like this

```
function loadImages(){
   var num = 1;
   $('.myElement').each(function(){
      var image = $("<img>").attr("src",mySrc).load(function(){
         if(num == 1){
            //do something - does not work
         }
      });       
      num++;
   });
}
```

And condition if(num == 1) does not work at all. I think, it's because while first image will be loaded, each() function still works and var num has some greater value, as my condition inside load() function goes to play... how can I fix it?

thx

full function code

```
function loadThumbs(imageCount){
var perc = 0;
var cache = [];
var thumbHolderWidth = 0;
var thumbHolderHeight = 0;
$('#thumbs').find(".image_thumb").each(function(enumThumb){
    if(enumThumb == 0){
          $(this).addClass('active');
    }                               
    var thisThumbSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var smallim = $("<img>").attr("src",thisThumbSrc).load(function(){
        var thumbWidth = this.width;
        var thumbHeight = this.height;
        thumbHolderWidth = thumbHolderWidth + thumbWidth + 12;
        if(thumbHeight > thumbHolderHeight){
            thumbHolderHeight = thumbHeight;
        }
        });
        cache.push(smallim);

    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('bigimg');
    var im = $("<img>").attr("src",imgSrc).load(function(){
        if(enumThumb == 0){
            imWidth = this.width;
            imHeight = this.height;
            resizeOverlay(imWidth,imHeight,imgSrc);
        }
        perc = perc + (100/imageCount);
        var loaderWidth = Math.round(winWidth*perc/100);
        $('#thumb_loader').stop().animate({'width':loaderWidth+'px'});
        if(Math.round(perc) >= 100){
            $('#thumb_loader').animate({
                'height':'1px',
                'margin-top':'0px'
            },'fast',function(){
                $('#thumb_loader').addClass('loaded');
            });
        }
    });
    cache.push(im);
});
$('#images_overlay').find('#thumbs').css({
    'width':thumbHolderWidth+'px',
    'height':thumbHolderHeight+10+'px',
    'left':winWidth/2-thumbHolderWidth/2+'px'
})
$('#images_overlay').find('#thumbs').fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Does the load handler execute at all?

Comment: Your example is too contrived. What does `num` represent? (Should `num++` be inside the loop?)

Comment: Btw, it's true, all load handlers reference the same `num` variable, which value will always be 2.

Comment: Yes, sure, num++ have to be inside of loop and serves to enumerate elements

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's `each` method provides the index to the callback function. You don't need a dedicated iterator variable.

```
$( '.myElement' ).each(function ( i ) {
    // use i here
});
```

Comment: tnx, i'm just not a coder and do know very little about jquery. Thx for tipp, it's useful, i always use var for this )

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not passing correct `mySrc` value.

`mySrc` should be something like `YourImage.jpg`

```
$('<img>').attr('src', mySrc).load(function() {  
  alert('Image Loaded');  
});
```

> **Why you need to use `num++`? You can get the index of the element with each function itself.**

Comment: @Sobakinet: If you can provide a demo, it would be greater. You can use **[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)**

Comment: it's not really easy to provide some demo, it's about images, that are loaded via json, but i've added full function code

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the `$.each` function with the `for` loop. There is no need for the `num` variable or to increment it.

Here's an example of what you could to with all the features of the $.each function.

```
function loadImages(){
  $('.myElement').each(function(i, el){
    var image = $('<img>', {
      src: 'myimage'+i+'.jpg' // Loads a different image for each element.
    }).load(function(){
      image.hide().appendTo( $(el) ).fadeIn();  // Once loaded, appends image to .myElement and fades it in
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thx again, i've understood, that there is no need in special var with each() function. But in my case i have some similar elements (image thumbnalis) i become with JSON ind i have to do a loop through them. And urls of images are some attributes from thumbnails. Please see a coode i've added to my question...

Answer (score 0):

The `num` you created is inside the scope of he function `loadImages`, once the `each` is finished the value of `num` wil be its maximum value. Now `'load'` is an asynchronous thing, it gets called even after `each` is finished, at that time the value of 'num' should be maximum value. So for each call of `load` `num` is already at its max, and `num==1` is never met

One solution can be like:

```
function loadImages(){
   $('.myElement').each(function(num){
     var image = $("<img>")
       .attr("src",mySrc)
       .load((function(numAlias){
         return function() {
            if(numAlias == 1){
            //do something - does not work
            }
          }
      })(num));       
   });
}
```

More Explanation on creating a sub-scope for each iteration can be found here, [Return a function from the anonymous wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200279/return-a-function-from-the-anonymous-wrapper)

There can also be browser specific situation where load event might seem missed when setting src before attaching load. The problem was there before, not sure if its fixed, like there was bugs with Chrome for cahced images sometimes.

Adding src after load look like a reliable way.

```
var image = $("<img>").load(function(){
         if(num == 1){
            //do something - does not work
         }
      }).attr("src",mySrc);
```