# JavaScript: How to set for setInterval function a custom behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, setinterval

I need to set a custom behaviour for the `setInterval` js function;

This is part of a online game, and this script is used to keep the data updated;

`worlds[world_id].building` is the traffic light, with `true` for grren and `false` for red values, just to know;

I used the following function to obtain a array;

This is a `js` function:

```
function init() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/robots/default/loadWorlds',
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    if (data.status === true) {
                        if (data.worlds) {
                            worlds = data.worlds;
                            $.each(data.worlds, function(key, value) {
                                addElement(key, value);
                                count_world_ids++;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json',
        });
    }
```

the `js` function calls this `php` method:

```
public function actionLoadWorlds() {
        $worlds = array();
        $status = true;
        $result = array(
            'worlds' => &$worlds,
            'status' => &$status,
        );
        $model_worlds = WorldM::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('status' => WorldM::ACTIVE));
        if ($model_worlds) {
            $ind = 0;
            foreach ($model_worlds as $key => $model_world) {
                $ind++;
                $worlds[$ind] = array(
                    'id' => $model_world->id,
                    'battle' => true,
                    'building' => true,
                    'troop' => true,
                    'resources' => true,
                );
            }
        } else {
            $status = false;
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
```

Now that I have obtained my array, I can do a `each`, ass seen in the `js` function and call the `addElement` js function;

Within the `addElement` js function, after I insert all the `div` elements needed, i will call this js functions:

```
   setInterval(function() {
    fBattle(value['id']);
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
    fBuilding(value['id']);
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
    fTroop(value['id']);
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
    fVillageResources(value['id']);
}, 1000);
```

So, for each world, those functions will be triggered, at a 1 second interval;

If I have 10 worlds, `fBattle(value['id']);` will be triggered for 10 times;

Now, comes the issue:

Why the `fBattle` triggers at the same time for all the worlds?

It has a different param, from 1 to ... n worlds;

Also, within the `fBattle` function there is a traffic light, and if the job is not finished , it should not trigger;

This process should be `async`, because on different worlds, the job might not be finished;

```
function fBattle(world_id) {
        if (worlds[world_id].battle == true) {
            worlds[world_id].battle = false;
            document.getElementById('battlePermission' + world_id).innerText = 'working';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/robots/battle/test',
                data: {},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('battle ' + world_id);
                    console.log(data);
                    worlds[world_id].battle = true;
                    document.getElementById('battlePermission' + world_id).innerText = 'finished';
                },
                dataType: 'json',
            });
        }
    }
```

for now, this is the job for each action:

```
public function actionTest() {
        $sleep = rand(1, 10);
        sleep($sleep);
        echo json_encode(array('result' => true, 'sleep' => $sleep));
        exit;
    }
```

I know that this action is triggered in the same time for all the worlds, and the `rand` value is the same for the same `js` function;

Comment: Its hard to understand the whole setup, but here is a common misconeption clarified http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200279/return-a-function-from-the-anonymous-wrapper

Comment: you are probably calling the same `id` the last `id` 10 times, if you dont have the scope bound to anonymous function. Try `console.log(world_id)` in fBattle to confirm `ids` are different

Comment: And with your setup, you probably needs some recursive calls, may be coupled with `setTimeout`

Comment: it is a different id; i checked; i might have found the solution; will test