# example of closure with setTimeOut()

Tags: javascript, closures

Can someone explain to me why the code does not act as expected?

WHy would this happen? I know it is due to "scoping", but I don't know the exact mechanism.

"Considering the above code, the console will display four identical messages "The value undefined is at index: 4". "

```
const arr = [10, 12, 15, 21];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
           console.log(`The value ${arr[i]} is at index: ${i}`);
      }, (i+1) * 1000);
}
```

declare i using 'let' solves the problem;

putting setTimeOut() into IIFE also solves the problem, but I could not understand why.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200279/return-a-function-from-the-anonymous-wrapper)

Comment: If you know, it is because of 'scoping', why not read up on it? There are plenty of resources on the web and StackOverflow is not really ment for teaching.

Comment: It is a common gotcha that functions defined in for loops don't work as you may expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**let** allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the **var** keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.